# Why is my BFS algorithm returning + 1 rather than the correct amount of steps that it took to reach the destination?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to learn BFS and I've noticed that my implementation returns `5` rather than `4` which is the correct amount of steps it takes to reach it's destination which is the bottom right of the grid. (`grid[grid.Length - 1][grid.Length - 1]`)

The grid I'm giving it looks like this

```
int[][] grid = new[]
{
    new int[] { 0, 0, 0 },
    new int[] { 1, 1, 0 },
    new int[] { 1, 1, 0 }
};
```

And this returns 5, rather than 4.

But this grid returns 2 when it's suppose to be 2, why is this one returning the correct value but not the other one?

```
int[][] grid = new[]
{
    new int[] { 0, 1},
    new int[] { 1, 0}
};
```

And then the actual algorithm is implemented like so

```
int[][] dirs = new[]
{
    new[] { 0, 1 }, //Bottom
    new[] { 1, 1 }, //Bottom right
    new[] { 1, 0 }, //Right
    new[] { 1, -1 }, //Top right
    new[] { 0, -1 }, //Top
    new[] { -1, -1 }, //Top left
    new[] { -1, 0 }, //Left
    new[] { -1, 1 } //Bottom left
};

public int BinaryMatrix(int[][] grid)
{
    /* Length of the rows */
    var rowLength = grid.Length;

    /* The length of each col */
    var colLength = grid[0].Length;

    /* Can't find a path */
    if (grid[0][0] == 1 || grid[rowLength - 1][colLength - 1] == 1)
        return -1;

    var Queue = new Queue<int[]>(); /* Coordinates */

    /* Make a copy of the grid on order to update and perform checks without manipulating the original one. */
    int[][] visited = new int[rowLength][];

    for (int i = 0; i < visited.Length; i++)
        visited[i] = new int[colLength];

    Queue.Enqueue(new[] { 0, 0 });
    visited[0][0] = 1;
    int steps = 1;

    while (Queue.Count != 0)
    {
        int[] coord = Queue.Dequeue();

        var cy = coord[0]; /* Y */
        var cx = coord[1]; /* X */

        /* If what we just popped has the same coordinates as the destination */
        if (cy == rowLength - 1 && cx == colLength - 1) return steps;

        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
        {
            int neighborY = dirs[i][0] + cy;
            int neighborX = dirs[i][1] + cx;

            /* Bounds check */
            if (neighborX >= 0 && neighborX < colLength && neighborY >= 0 && neighborY < rowLength)
            {
                /* Visited check */
                if (visited[neighborY][neighborX] == 0 && grid[neighborY][neighborX] == 0)
                {
                    Queue.Enqueue(new[] { neighborY, neighborX });
                    visited[neighborY][neighborX] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        steps++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Does diagonal movement count as two ? Else your second example is wrong, and should have a total of one step. The problem is that you start the steps counter at 1, when you didn't make any yet. BTW, you inverted `x` and `y` coordinate in the direction, or in the algorithm, but there is inconsistency between your comments and the way you use them.

Comment: Diagonal movements should count as one step, wouldn't that still make it right though? Since the first step would be the starting point, and then moving diagonally 1 step makes it 2.

Comment: ok. Then it's because you increment for each cell you visit, even if it's not in the final path. Try your code on an empty grid and see. You should add the step number in the queue with the cell, and use this instead of a global counter

Comment: I added an outer for loop to loop over the "levels" so that I can increment per level basis and it seems to be working fine